# React: How do I access an array defined inside a component from another file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have an array that's defined in a component in its own file, and I'd like to use that array in another file (or in the same file but out of scope, if that would make more sense).

**array.js**

```
const Container = ({ results }) => {
  const arrayCreated = results.map(
    (a: { keyword: string }) => ({
      label: a.keyword,
      value: a.keyword
    }))
  console.log(arrayCreated);
  return arrayCreated;
} 

export default Container;
```

`console.log()` above shows the array as intended.

I'm struggling to figure out how I can use `arrayCreated` in different ways in other files:

**main.js**

```
import Container from './array.js'

// example 1 

const promiseOptions = () =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(arrayCreated);
    }, 1000);

// example 2 

<select options={arrayCreated} />
```

I've tried tons of different combos, so far nothing has worked. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is not React related, and your code appears unrelated to React.  If it is, and you are trying to access state variables inside of child components, that is an antipattern and you're supposed to move the state higher.   Now, the problem here is that you are trying to access `arrayCreated` like a global variable.  You need to call `const arrayCreated = Container({results: /*some value you input */})` where you are using that function.

Comment: If you want to manipulate the array. You can directly do that in Main.js and you can pass it inside the select component

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code has some syntax error.

To get the internal variable you need to execute the `Container` function

`const result = Container(input);` will store the arrayCreated in result variable.